# How to migrate from Shopify to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, migration, script

I'm having many clients migrating from Shopify to Magento 2, and the data migration usually happens via ERP, but for some clients, it's not possible.

How could I import to my Magento 2 the Shopify data?

Is there a script (bash, PHP, JS, etc...) to do it via API?

Answer (score 1):

you can export shopify data and convert it to magento import,

https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-online/online-store/how-do-i-duplicate-my-store

**Backups and duplication**

> You can export CSV files from your Shopify admin to back up your store
>   information. You can combine these CSV files with other data (for
>   example, a copy of your theme) to create a backup or duplicate of your
>   store.

using API export/import script:

https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-migrate-from-shopify-to-magento-2-or-sync-data-between-them.html#Migrate_from_Shopify_to_Magento_2_via_API

> Alternatively, the Improved Import & Export Magento 2 extension allows
>   connecting to Shopify directly. The module lets you replace file
>   transfers with REST or SOAP API connections. The following tutorial
>   describes this process:

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely **import data directly** from Shopify to Magento 2 **via API**. You should find a reliable automated migration tool to help you complete the migration process successfully, to clarify, transfer all data including products, customers, orders and other related data from your old store on Shopify to the new one on Magento2, without interrupting your current store performance.

If you have some technical skills, you can try this solution: **export data** on your Shopify store as **CSV files** then import manually those CSV files to Magento 2. However, this way will **take you a lot of time and effort**. You need to be careful during the migration process because there are many **differences in structure** between 2 platforms, so there might be **some expected issues**.